Unable to get SELECT SQL query result in VBScript
I'm using VBScript to access SQL Server and the configuration is ok as it works when inserting new values and even when changing the columns names.
However, now I want to get the name of the columns and I'am able to get the first record, but not the second and the third.
The format of the SQL query results are output in a single column with three rows.
Here's the documentation but I cannot get anything clear:(.
My code:
Function getColumnNames(tableName)
    Dim sql, rst
    rst = "result1, result2, result3" 'resultX are string tags
    sql = "SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('" & "precios"& "') ORDER BY column_id ASC"
    $DBExecute("sqlExpress", sql, rst)
    MsgBox $result1
    MsgBox $result2
    MsgBox $result3
End Function

$result1 stores correctly the value while $result2 and $result3 are blank. I have tried several ways, as definining rst as:
rst = "result" 'result is a string array from 0 to 2
rst = "result(1), result(2), result(3)" 'result is a string array from 0 to 2

No one worked. Can anyone help me? Thanks.
NOTE: I'm working on Aveva Edge SCADA software, or Indusoft

What is $DBExecute? VBScript didn't have its own database methods but always used ADO. I'd expect to see ADODB.Connection and ADODB.Recordset objects. I say used because VBScript is obsolete since 2006, when it was fully replaced by Powershell for scripting

forgot to say that I'm working on Aveva Edge SCADA software, or Indusoft

Doesn't change the fact there's no $DBExecute or $result1. In fact, VBScript didn't allow variables starting with $. Are you sure you're looking at the correct documentation ?

That's not VBScript. Just because some random company decided to call its scripting language VBScript doesn't mean it is VBScript. There's an appendix in that site that describes the syntax of that weird language. I dare say that if Microsoft knew about it they'd sue them to oblivion for copyright trademark violation. And after looking at that ad-infested "technical reference" site I'd add defamation.

I suspect you can get the value by result[0] or $result[0] but i'd probably read the documentation

I finally got this solution. It works. And yes, it is for Indusoft o Aveva Edge.
Function getColumnNames(tableName)
    Dim sql, numCur, numRows, row, txt
    sql ="Select name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('" & tableName & "') ORDER BY column_id Asc"
    numCur = $DBCursorOpenSQL("sqlExpress", sql)
    numRows = $DBCursorRowCount(numCur)

    For row=1 To numRows
      $namesInDB[row-1] =  $DBCursorGetValue(numCur,"name")
      $DBCursorNext(numCur)
    Next

    $variablesInDB = numRows
    $DBCursorClose(numCur)
   
End Function


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
